# How can I position the image and then click it and do the remove function jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

Click http://jsfiddle.net/4y1b1j8g/25/ to see the result. I want to move the cross sign to the right side which will not appear over the text. I want it to be like Stackoverflow tag. And then click the image and remove it. I've try to use `$(removePic).click.(function() { $(removePic).remove()}):`, but it is not working.

```js
var removePic = $('.test').css({'background-image' : 'url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/16x16/DeleteRed.png)',
'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat',
'background-position' : 'right'})
```

```css
.test {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 3px 0 0;
    border:solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" id="test0">dog</div>
<div class="test" id="test1">lion</div>
<div class="test" id="test2">cat</div>
```

Comment: `$('.test').on('click', function() { $(this).remove(); }`?

Comment: As your error tells you, you've got a `:` colon  instead of a `;` semicolon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").append('<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/16x16/DeleteRed.png">');   
    $(document).on("click", ".test img", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/4y1b1j8g/28/)**